# Android Application Runs on Emulator, Crashes on Phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I've been struggling to get this program to run on my phone consistently. It basically allows the user to take a picture from a button press and subsequently read the RGB values by touching a picture. I've gotten it to work maybe twice, with no changes to the code, but most of the time it "stops unexpectedly" and crashes. I have not gotten it to work twice in a row. However, the same code works perfectly in the emulator. In the error log it says that the program fails to execute when assigning a bitmap to the Image View. I checked to make sure the minimum and target SDK's match the phone model's Android software. The phone I'm using is a Motorola Droid X. Help would be greatly appreciated! The log cat is included below as well. EDIT: Also note that if I put in a dummy RGB value the program doesn't crash.

```
SOURCE

package com.example.firstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity { //1

    TextView pixelcord, rgbvals; 
    ImageView iv;
    Button btn;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //2

        /* GATHER THE INFORMATION FROM THE LAYOUT TO ORGANIZE APP*/
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* SET ON CLICK LISTENER TO GET CLICK REPSONSE -- LAUNCH CAMERA AND TAKE PHOTO */
        /* SET VARIABLES FOR USE FROM EACH VIEW */
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView); /* USE IMAGE VIEW FIELD*/
        pixelcord = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pixelcord); /* USE TEXT FIELD FOR PIXEL */
        rgbvals = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rgbvals); /* USE TEXT FIELD FOR RGB VALUES*/
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takePhoto);

        /* SET INFORMATION OF WHAT TO DO UPON EACH CLIK*/
        iv.setOnTouchListener(imgSourceOnTouchListener);

/* =====================================CAMERA BUTTON=====================================*/        
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //3

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) { //4

                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            } //*4


        }); //*3
/* =======================================================================================*/        


        } /* END OF ON CREATE*/ //*2

    /* DECLARATION OF IMG TOUCH FUNCTION*/

    OnTouchListener imgSourceOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() { //5

        @Override

        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) { //6


            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();
            float[] eventXY = new float[] { eventX, eventY};

            Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix(); 
            ((ImageView)view).getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

            invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY); 
            int x = Integer.valueOf((int)eventXY[0]); /* POTENTIALLY REDUNDANT*/
            int y = Integer.valueOf((int)eventXY[1]);

            /* CHECK TO MAKE SURE VALUES ARE WITHIN BITMAP RANGE*/


            /* SET TEXT FUNCTION TO THE FIELD USING SET TEXT METHOD*/
            pixelcord.setText("X:" + String.valueOf(eventX) + "/ Y:" + String.valueOf(eventY) ); 

            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); 
            int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

            rgbvals.setText("Color Value" + "#" + Integer.toHexString(touchedRGB));
            rgbvals.setTextColor(touchedRGB);

            return true;

        } //*6


    }; //*5

    @Override

    public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    { //7
        if(requestCode == 0)
        { //8
            Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);

        } //*8
    } //*7


} //*1
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.seniordesign"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.seniordesign.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LayOut XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:orientation = "vertical">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/takePhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Take Photo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pixelcord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/takePhoto"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/takePhoto"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:text="Pixel Coordinates:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rgbvals"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pixelcord"
        android:layout_below="@+id/takePhoto"
        android:text="RGB Values:" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank's in advance for the help!

EDIT: LOGCAT

```
2013-10-30 09:57:39.061 E 5001/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x must be < bitmap.width()
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelAccess(Bitmap.java:824)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixel(Bitmap.java:779)
    at com.example.seniordesign.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:90)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3881)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1919)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1186)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2142)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1903)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2194)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please post your LogCat

Comment: Ok, I'll type it up and post it now

Comment: Just posted it, posted the fatal section of the logcat

Comment: Might be due to resolution difference between your real phone and emulator! Check if this is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It crashes because the value of x is bigger than the width of the image. I guess its on this point:

```
int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
```

The image you set in your view does not have to be the same size as the view itself. It could be either bigger or smaller. What you could try is to get the percentage of the point pressed on the view and use that percentage to calculate the position on the image.

That way the position will be the same as the position of the image. If the image is stretched ofcourse.

Comment: This was the problem -- I made the Image View fillup the remainder of the screen and now it works consistently. Thank you!